# Клавиатура vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я вот сделал бота и добавил админов в базу, ну  вот у них есть клавиатура, как эту клавиатуру скрыть от других? Чтобы эту клавиатуру видели только те , кто есть в базе данных админов :D

Comment: вы можете проверять id отправителя сообщения, если оно есть в базе, тогда отправлять клавиатуру, иначе - нет.

Comment: ну я так и сделал XD проверяет, если есть, она отправляет клаву , и эта клава видна всем

Comment: код хотя-бы приведи, как мне вообще возможно подсказать тебе что-то, если я вообще не в курсе о чём конкретно речь? вот тебе полезная инфа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask